# Computational efficient way to find a SL(2,Z) matrix between two set of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, coordinate-transformation

Suppose I have two sets of vectors (let's say it 2d, but it would be nice to generalize it to arbitrary dimensions):

$(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$ and $(v'_1,v'_2,\ldots,v'_n)$

and they have integer entries, and I know there is a SL(2,Z) matrix connected them. They are matrices with determinant=1 and with integer entries. The point is to find the matrix, efficiently. Basically the change of basis matrix. However, I don't know which vector is going in the transformed, so I would like some way that does not need to try and error with all of them.

I agree that the transformations could be multiples, but I'm interested in one transformation, not in all the possibilities.

Comment: Perhaps you could give some sample vectors to test out any answers here?

Comment: Also, are you saying that the matrix of $V_1$ is related to $V_2$ by both a change of basis and a permutation matrix s.t $V_2 = P B V_1$, or do the vectors match up ?

Comment: You can use the fact that the sums of the $v_i$ and $v^\prime_i$ are related by the same $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ matrix to solve for two of the three coefficients. I haven't been able to come up with a way to efficiently fix the third, but having only a single coefficient should make a brute force approach at least simpler. Unfortunately this does not scale well, as we are only able to fix $N$ of $(N^2-1)$ parameters this way (for $\text{SL}(N,\mathbb{Z})$).

Comment: @flinty You can use this `Dot @@ MapIndexed[If[OddQ@@#2, MatrixPower[{{0, -1}, {1, 0}}, #1], MatrixPower[{{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, #1]] &, RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, {10}]]` to generate random $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ matrices.

Comment: Did you intend SL(n,Z)? Also a concrete example should be added to the post.

Comment: Interesting problem, but does it specifically need Mathematica? I think math.stackexchange is a better venue.

Comment: @Hausdorff Can you please elaborate on how can you find two coefficients. I think the rest is trivial.

Comment: @yarchik I posted an example below

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add an example, since I am curious whether there is a simple answer.

Take for example the matrix $M$ and the two sets of vectors $v_i$, $v^\prime_i$ as follows

```
M = {{-221, 20}, {11, -1}};
v = {{11, 36}, {-40, -44}, {14, 49}, {-11, -9}, {-34, 21}};
vP = {{-2114, 105}, {7934, -395}, {7960, -396}, {-1711, 85}, {2251, -112}};
```

To recover `M` up to a single coefficient we can use the linearity:

```
MVar = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
sol = First@Solve[{MVar.Plus@@v == Plus@@vP, Det[MVar] == 1}, 
    {a, b, c, d}, Integers] /. ConditionalExpression[a_, __] :> a // Simplify;
MVar /. sol
```

> ```
> {{758739 + 758960 C[1], 859220 + 859200 C[1]}, 
>  {-37778 - 37789 C[1], -42781 - 42780 C[1]}}
> ```

For `C[1]->-1` we recover the original matrix `M`

```
MVar /. sol /. {C[1]->-1}
```

> ```
> {{-221, 20}, {11, -1}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, Haursdorff, this seems to work well. I wonder if there could be some problem in the case you have vectors that are {x,y}, {-w,-z} and {w-x,z-y}. With this method they will cancel out and their contribution won't be considered, right?
However, this is very smart, and for the example you gave us, it seems to work. I'll think about it

Answer (score 0):

The special linear group is defined by

[image: definition]

In words: SL(2,ℤ) is the group of 2 × 2 real matrices with determinant one. SL(2,ℤ) = {A ∈ Z2×2 : Det(A) = 1}

In representation theory:

SL(2,ℤ) is a real, non-compact simple Lie group, with the Lie-Algebra of the  `Tr`-free {\displaystyle 2\times 2}2\times 2-Matrices.

[image]

A vector space bass of this 3-dimensional vector is sl(2,ℤ)  for example

[image: base]

with the commutator relations:

[image: commutators]

The matrices out of SL(2,ℤ) corresponds to invertible relations in [image: Reals]. The matrices conserve the form of the volume but not the metrics in general.

How to generate matrices in SL(2,ℤ)?

The starting point and base of the strategy are selecting the elements of the first column coprime. Mathematica has the built-in Coprime and solves for the elements of the second column via the defining determinant equation equal one.

```
SL[a_, b_] := 
 If[CoprimeQ[a, b], Solve[a x - b y == 1, {x, y} \[Element] Integers],
   False]
```

---

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[1 + 6 C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers], 
  y -> ConditionalExpression[1 + 7 C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
```

This is a one-dimensional generator for this matrices and as mighty as Integers. So three matrice elements have to be defined to solve for the forth.

Just subgroups can be generated by suitable chosen matrices. These matrices built semi-groups. To show identities between these is considered NP-complete. I consider my answer close to that of @daniellichtblau. The question needs more concretions.

Comment: I do not see how this finds a particular conversion matrix to go from one set of integer vectors to another.